# Makecert and the asymmetrics keys

Tags: makecert

Is it possible to use makecert in order to generate ECRSA, Diffie-Hellman, EC Diffie-Hellman asymmetric public keys and DSA, ECDSA for the private keys.

Comment: Makecert and asymetriques Keys

Comment: WTF would ECRSA be? And there is no such thing as DH or ECDH keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use makecert for things other than RSA and DSA. If you need elliptic curve keys and certificate, you have to use other tools like the OpenSSL command line which has a more comprehensive support.